# How to configure CDN or Azure blob storage in Azure application gateway?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-cdn

Is it possible to expose azure blob storage and azure CDN through Azure Application Gateway.

If possible please share the guidelines.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, this scenario is Unsupported for now. You can leave your feedback for the same in this link - https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking